# How to allow “/” in then name of an enum member?

Tags: c#, syntax, enums

how to allow string with / in enum?

```
 enum basePath
    {
        student/getAllStudent,
        employee/getAllEmployee
    };
```

Sample code appreciated, thanks

Comment: That's not allowed by the language standard. So I think there is no work around for this. Can you elaborate on why you need to have `/` in enum ?

Comment: You can't. It seems like you're trying to use enums in a way they're not intended to be used.

Comment: You can only use letters, digits, and the underscore character when naming objects in c#.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: `allow string` [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) members cannot be strings.

Comment: `student_getAllStudent`, though an `enum` possibly isn't what you want here.

Comment: Consider `[Description("employee/getAllEmployee")]
        getAllEmployee,` Or a `Dictionary<basePath, string>` - either will allow you to associate a string with an enum entry.

Comment: Instead of enum you can create a static class with public static string fields.

Comment: @RufusL I mean the field with simple name but values with `/` assigned to them... `public  static string Employee = "employee/getAllEmployee";`

Comment: this looks like file paths, not a good place for an enum

Answer (score 4):

You can use Description Attribute from System.ComponentModel namespace and make enum like

```
using System.ComponentModel;
enum basePath
{
    [Description("student/getAllStudent")]
    GetAllStudent,
    [Description("employee/getAllEmployee")]
    GetAllEmployee
}
```

Now to access description, add following helper method by creating a class like below

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum GenericEnum) //Hint: Change the method signature and input paramter to use the type parameter T
    {
        Type genericEnumType = GenericEnum.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memberInfo = genericEnumType.GetMember(GenericEnum.ToString());
        if (memberInfo != null && memberInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            var _Attribs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (_Attribs != null && _Attribs.Count() > 0)
            {
                return ((System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)_Attribs.ElementAt(0)).Description;
            }
        }
        return GenericEnum.ToString();
    }

}
```

Now you can get the description by calling

```
basePath.GetAllStudent.GetDescription();
```

BUT MY SUGGESSION IS TO USE A STATIC CLASS LIKE BELOW

```
public static class MyPaths
{
     public static readonly string GET_ALL_STUDENT = "student/getAllStudent"; 
     public static readonly string GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES = "employee/getAllEmployees";
}

//and then use like 
MyPaths.GET_ALL_STUDENT;
```